# Maven: Verify that maven can access a repository

Tags: maven

My company has it's own maven repository, works great, no problems.
Is there a way to get maven to check that it can read this repository without having to go through the build cycle?  I know I can just try the URL in a web browser but that's not quite the same.

I was thinking of something like `mvn ping-repository {URL}` or perhaps a simple plug-in.
Below is our repository in my maven configuration, just in case.

Thanks!  Much obliged.

```
            <repository>
                <id>companyRepository</id>
                <name>Company repository</name>                             
                <url>http://ourcompany.com/repository/maven-public/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
```

Comment: Why do you need that? What is the purpose of that "ping.." ?

Comment: To verify that maven is correctly configured

Comment: Why not just run a build? I mean, you only need to do it once, why does it need to be fast?

Comment: My assumption is that you have configured in your pom file? Or correctly in your `settings.xml` ? On your ci server that should be done on the CI Server... You will see if something is wrongly configured during your build... that's the best test you can have... a ping like ? What should it test?

Comment: It should test that maven can access the repository as cited in the question.